# mandatory field for dropdown but optional for textbox in view model class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page to insert data regarding customer information.

```
public class CustomerModel
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }        
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public AddressModel Addresses { get; set; }   
    }
    
public class AddressModel
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        [Required]      
        public string AddressName { get; set; }
    }
```

Employee will insert the data of each new Customer. Suppose a customer comes whose address is not present in the database, new address textbox is there in the page, they will fill that textbox and save. In such case, the new filled address id should automatically bound to the customer address. Please see the attached image for page design.

I have created a `view model` to achieve this, but do not know how to create the attributes for address. Because, when address is present in the dropdown, the user do not have to fill the new address textbox but when the address is not present in the dropdown the user will fill the address text box.

```
public class CustomerInfoViewModel
    {
        
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }  
        
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        
        public string AddressName
    }
```

[image]

Comment: How many addresses your customer can have?

Comment: @Serge customer can have multiple addresses. Thank you!